# Data Normalization is disrupting the code

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, normalization

I'm using Keras with tensorflow and the code I made works without the data normalization, but whenever I try to use it this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projeto_SISTCA\Keras_Ex1_versao2.py", line 64, in <module>
    previsoes=model.predict(teste)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1727, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1569 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1559 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1552 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1525 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:380 call
        return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:420 call
        return self._run_internal_graph(
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:556 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1013 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:251 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 100000 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

I'm using numpy arrays as an input, one has random integers from 18 to 90 and the other has 0's and 1's, the data normalization seems to be changing the array's dimension, but I'm not sure. Here's the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random as rd
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import dtype, shape

x = 100000
y = 100

treino_amostras = np.empty(x, dtype=int)
label_amostras = np.empty(x, dtype=int)
teste = np.empty(y, dtype=int)


for i in range(0,30000):
    p = rd.randint(18,34)
    treino_amostras[i] = p
    label_amostras[i] = 1

for g in range(30000,50000):
    p = rd.randint(35,90)
    treino_amostras[g] = p
    label_amostras[g] = 1

for m in range(50000,70000):
    p = rd.randint(18,34)
    treino_amostras[m] = p
    label_amostras[m] = 0


for l in range(70000, x):
    p = rd.randint(35,90)
    treino_amostras[l] = p
    label_amostras[l] = 0


treino_amostras=tf.keras.utils.normalize(treino_amostras, axis=0)

print(label_amostras.shape)
print(treino_amostras.shape)

def shuffling(a, b):
    shu = np.random.permutation(len(a)) 
    return a[shu], b[shu]

treino_amostras, label_amostras=shuffling(treino_amostras, label_amostras)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(treino_amostras, label_amostras, epochs=5)

for k in range(0,y):
        p = rd.randint(18,90)
        teste[k] = p

previsoes=model.predict(teste)

while(1):
    try:
        num_per=input("Introduza o numero de pessoas (de 1 a 100): ")
        if (num_per=="quit"):
            break 
        num_per=int(num_per)
        if (num_per>100 or num_per<1):
            print("Erro, escolha um numero de 1 a 100")
            continue
        for f in range(0, num_per):
            #previ = np.argmax(previsoes[f])
            print("Tenho", teste[f],"anos e a probabilidade de ter um animal de estimação:", previsoes[f,1])
    except ValueError:
        print("Erro, escolha um numero de 1 a 100")
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You are normalizing on the wrong axis, you are normalizing across samples, and it should be across features.

Comment: How do I do that?